# What's the rst equivalent of markdown named links?

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext

In markdown, I can do this:

```
Imagine a long paragraph here, with [an extended phrase linked
to something elsewhere][shortref].

[shortref]: http://really-long-and-annoying-link-here
```

What's the equivalent syntax in reStructuredText?

Answer (score 3):

You could define a [substitution](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) with a replacement and a reference to the corresponding hyperlink target.

```
Imagine a long paragraph here, with |SR|_.

.. |SR| replace:: an extended phrase linked to something elsewhere
.. _SR: http://really-long-and-annoying-link-here
```

Another option is not an exact equivalent, but is still close:

```
Imagine a long paragraph here, with `an extended phrase linked
to something elsewhere`_.

Here is a short reference link: `shortref`_.

.. _shortref: `an extended phrase linked to something elsewhere`_
.. _an extended phrase linked to something elsewhere: http://really-long-and-annoying-link-here
```

The example above uses a combination of [external and indirect hyperlink targets](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets).